# c++ - Linked List with template (error c2039)

Tags: c++, templates

Hello I have a problem I can not solve and I do not understand why, I would be happy to explain what the problem and how to solve it.

Everything seems fine to me. I do not understand where the problem is.

the error i get (and more mistakes, it's just too much to write down everything):

```
Error   7   error C2039: 'getData' : is not a member of '`global namespace''    
c:\projects\linkelisted\ListNode.h  31  1   LinkeListed
Error   26  error C2039: 'getNewNode' : is not a member of 'List'   
c:\projects\linkelisted\List.h  127 1   LinkeListed
Error   6   error C2039: 'ListNode' : is not a member of '`global 
namespace'' 
c:\projects\linkelisted\ListNode.h  26  1   LinkeListed
Error   5   error C2059: syntax error : '<' 
c:\projects\linkelisted\ListNode.h  26  1   LinkeListed
```

ListNode.h:

```
#ifndef LISTNODE_H
#define LISTNODE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class NODETYPE> List;
template<class NODETYPE>
class ListNode {
friend class List<NODETYPE>;

private:
NODETYPE data;
ListNode<NODETYPE> *nextPtr;

public:
ListNode(const NODETYPE &);
NODETYPE getData()const;
};

template<class NODETYPE>
ListNode <NODETYPE>::ListNode(const NODETYPE &info) :data(info), nextPtr(0) 
{}

template<class NODETYPE>
NODETYPE ListNode<NODETYPE>::getData()const{
return data;
}
#endif
```

List.h:

```
#ifndef List_H
#define List_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

#include "ListNode.h"

template<class NODETYPE>
class List {
ListNode<NODETYPE> *firstPtr;
ListNode<NODETYPE> *lastPtr;
ListNode <NODETYPE> *getNewNode(const NODETYPE &value);

public:
List();
~List();
void insertAtFront(const NODETYPE &value);
void insertAtBack(const NODETYPE &value);
void removeFromFront(NODETYPE &value);
void removeFromBack(NODETYPE &value);
bool isEmpty()const;
void print()const;
};

template<class NODETYPE>
List<NODETYPE>::List() : firstPtr(0), lastPtr(0){
}

template<class NODETYPE>
List<NODETYPE>::~List(){
if (!isEmpty()){
    cout << "Destroying nodes ...\n";

    ListNode<NODETYPE> *currentPtr = firstPtr;
    ListNode<NODETYPE> *tempPtr;

    while (currentPtr != 0){
        tempPtr = currentPtr;
        cout << tempPtr->data << endl;
        delete tempPtr;
    }}}

template<class NODETYPE> 
void List<NODETYPE>::insertAtFront(const NODETYPE &value){
ListNode<NODETYPE> *newPtr = getNewNode(value);

if (isEmpty())
    firstPtr = lastPtr = newPtr;
else{
    newPtr->nextPtr = firstPtr;
    firstPtr = newPtr;
}}


template<class NODETYPE> 
void List<NODETYPE>::insertAtBack(const NODETYPE &value){
ListNode<NODETYPE> *newPtr = getNewNode(value);

if (isEmpty()) 
    firstPtr = lastPtr = newPtr;
else{
    lastPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
    lastPtr = newPtr;
}}

template<class NODETYPE>
bool List<NODETYPE>::removeFromFront(NODETYPE &value){
if (isEmpty())
    return false;
else{
    ListNode<NODETYPE> *tempPtr = firstPtr;

    if (firstPtr == lastPtr)
        firstPtr = lastptr = 0;
    else{
        firstPtr = firstPtr->nextPtr;   
        delete tempPtr;
        return true;
        value = tempPtr->data;
        } }}

template<class NODETYPE> 
bool List <NODETYPE>::removeFromBack(NODETYPE &value){
if (isEmpty())
    return false;
   else{
    ListNode<NODETYPE> *tempPtr = lastPtr;

    if (firstPtr == lastPtr)
        firstPtr = lastPtr = 0;
    else{
        ListNode<NODETYPE> *current = firstPtr;

        while (currentPtr->nextPtr != lastPtr)
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        lastPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr->nextPtr = 0;
    }
    value = tempPtr->data;
    delete tempPtr;
    return true;
     }
 }

template<class NODETYPE>
    bool List < NODETYPE >::isEmpty()const{
    return firstPtr == 0;
}

template<class NODETYPE>
ListNode<NODETYPE> *List <NODETYPE>::getNewNode(const NODETYPE &value){
    return new ListNode<NODETYPE>(value);
  }

  template<class NODETYPE> 
  void List<NODETYPE>::print()const{
    if (isEmpty()){
        cout << "The list is empty\n\n";
        return
    }

    ListNode<NODETYPE> *currentPtr = firstPtr;

    cout << "The list is: "; 

    while (currentPtr != 0){
        cout << currentPtr->data << endl;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
 }
 #endif
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "List.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

List <int> integerList;

integerList.isEmpty();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

thank's.

Comment: There are a *lot* of errors in your code -- syntax, typos, etc. I suggest you fix it [there on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70b4ab46d72f2b92), with Clang being much more helpful than MSVC in its diagnostics.

Comment: @Quentin thank's. but i dont see a lot of errors i think is something simple

Comment: Of course you don't see them, they wouldn't have reached here otherwise -- the compiler is not so lenient.

Comment: **()** The forward declaration should be `template<class NODETYPE> class List;` (add `class` keyword). **()** `removeFromFront` is declared to return `void`, but implemented to return `bool`. Same with `removeFromBack` **()** There is no variable named `lastptr`; you likely meant `lastPtr` **()** There's no variable named `currentPtr` either. **()** There's a missing semicolon after `return` in `print()`. With these fixed, your program [compiles](http://rextester.com/BHHBA88438)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Why not post that as an answer?